# SSRS Concatenated field parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

[image]

I need to create an SSRS report parameter by combining two fields the deliverable ID and deliverable name. I was able to do that using an SQL quire , however when I click on "View Report". I get an error message. My drop down list of parameters, my quire and the error message attached as images for your reference.

```
SELECT        CAST(DeliverableID AS NVARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(Name AS NVARCHAR) AS ConcatDeliverableName
FROM            DeliverableTasks
ORDER BY DeliverableID
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you using the parameter? Usually you would just use the **ID** field (`DeliverableID`) as a separate field for it in the query - have one field for the name (the parameter **Label**) and the other for the ID (the parameter **Value**). You display the LABEL in the parameter drop down but use the ID value for the parameter in a Filter or WHERE clause.

Comment: What is the data type for your parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with select that returns data for DataSet called RequiredParameters, and it says in error itself that it is about converting some nvarchar to int. You should try to execute just that sql script/sp to see if it runs properly.